# is there any way to batch restart deployment to apply config change in kubernetes v1.15.2

Tags: kubernetes

I an changed my kubernetes cluster(v1.15.2) configmap, now I want to make my config apply to all of my deployment in some namespace. What is the best practice to do? I am tried to do like this:

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment soa-report-consumer
```

but my cluster has so many deployment, should I write shell script to complete this task, any simple way?

Answer (score 2):

The usual fix for this is to use some automation from a tool like Kustomize or Helm so that the deployments automatically update when the config data changes.

Answer (score 2):

[ConfigMap Generator](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/reference/kustomize.html#configmapgenerator) of kustomize can be used for this.

`configMapGenerator` contains a list of ConfigMaps to generate.
By default, generated ConfigMaps will have a hash appended to the name. The ConfigMap hash is appended after a nameSuffix, if one is specified. Changes to ConfigMap data will cause a ConfigMap with a new name to be generated, triggering a rolling update to Workloads referencing the ConfigMap.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/configGeneration.md